# Labels on a d3 line chart

Tags: d3.js

I'm struggling to create labels for the end of my multiline chart in d3. I'm new to this, so I must be missing something. When I add the two chunks of code in to create labels for two of the lines it stops the chart showing up on my browser.

http://bl.ocks.org/resolutionfoundation/eaf769a515614ef700a5

For ref this is what it looks like without final two code chunks

http://bl.ocks.org/resolutionfoundation/f11023133e7ff4be8adc

Grateful for any help!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80298/discussion-on-question-by-roar2015-labels-on-a-d3-line-chart).

Answer (score 0):

Just for everyone else to know :

Here is the link to the correct problem :

http://bl.ocks.org/resolutionfoundation/5edbbfb9d5e4f8fd8931

The problem here was the y value for the labels were set like so :

```
data[0]
```

where he should have done something like this :

```
data[data.length-1]
```

which puts the labels at the correct height at the end of the line :)